# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.drools.compiler.compiler.Dialect.getId()"

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, kie

We have a drool based rule engine deployed on tomcat 9.0.63, java 17. I am using drools 9.44.0.Final version. when I deploy the code on AKS, I am getting intermittent issue mentioned in the screenshot.

We have yml based configuration for defining the rule. We are reading our DRL (yml configuration file), and using `StatelessKieSession`.

Below dependency we have used related to drool.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.kie</groupId>
<artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
<version>9.44.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

we are getting the below error while calling the getDialect() method from RuleBuilderContext.class from drools-compiler-9.44.0.Final.jar
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rsIz.png)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.drools.compiler.compiler.Dialect.getId()" because the return value of "org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuildContext.getDialect()" is null   at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuildContext.<init>(RuleBuildContext.java:86)   at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.buildRuleBuilderContext(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:259)   at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.lambda$compileRulesLevel$3(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:274)
```

Comment: Is that the _only_ drools dependency?

Comment: yes , kie-ci has all drool related dependency.

Comment: Hello, have you solved this problem in the meantime? I'm facing this issue as well. Thanks!

Comment: No, I am still facing the same issue. Its intermittent in nature.